# How can I process data with a lot of missing values because of different sources?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, data-cleaning, data-processing

I have data that looks like this:

| Timestamp | Variable A | Variable B | Variable C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Value | Nan | Nan |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00.050 | Value | Nan | Nan |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00.150 | Nan | Value | Value |
| 2023-01-01 05:00:00.450 | Nan | Value | Value |
| 2023-01-01 05:00:00.500 | Value | Nan | Nan |

Variable A comes from one source and Variable B and C from a second, so the timestamps are different which gives me a lot of missing data (the data comes from a dozen sources, this is just a simplified example).

I tried to use the [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) method of pandas.
But this method creates too many lines for me, in the example above there would be new lines between 2023-01-01 00:00:00.150 and 2023-01-01 05:00:00.450, which I do not want.

Can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to use the successive time difference and a threshold to group your data with [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) (or [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html)):

```
out = df.groupby(df['Timestamp'].diff().ge('1s').cumsum(), as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
                Timestamp  Variable A  Variable B  Variable C
0 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000         1.0         3.0         4.0
1 2023-01-01 05:00:00.450         7.0         5.0         6.0
```

With [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
out = df.resample('5H', on='Timestamp').mean().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
            Timestamp  Variable A  Variable B  Variable C
0 2023-01-01 00:00:00         1.5         3.0         4.0
1 2023-01-01 05:00:00         7.0         5.0         6.0
```

Used input:

```
                Timestamp  Variable A  Variable B  Variable C
0 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000         1.0         NaN         NaN
1 2023-01-01 00:00:00.050         2.0         NaN         NaN
2 2023-01-01 00:00:00.150         NaN         3.0         4.0
3 2023-01-01 05:00:00.450         NaN         5.0         6.0
4 2023-01-01 05:00:00.500         7.0         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is your context, but .fillna is a good method.

```
df = df.astype(str).fillna('')
```

It will change the columns to string and fill missing values with an empty string. I you need to keep a specific datatype you can do it separately and provide a filling value for each.